# While Converting excel to dataset using excelreader.Asdataset(), Sometimes after read an empty cell in excel, the next cell is read as System.DBNull

Tags: excel

I am converting excel file data to data set using following code
**if (String.Compare(Path.GetExtension(filePath), ".xlsx",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0){excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream); if (excelReader != null) {

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;var dsresult = new DataSet();

try { dsresult = excelReader.AsDataSet(); }}}**
But sometimes, after read an empty cell in excel, the next cell is read as System.DBNull 
e. g.
data in excel as below 
Col A = 1, Col B is blank, Col C = 2
After conversion to data set values in dataset will be
data set values:
Col A = 1, Col B is blank, Col C is blank

After searching it seems that there is some problem with excel reader, Please suggest some proper solution or atleast workaround for this issue

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with old versions of Excel Data reader, I had the same issue as you, tried excelreader.Asdataset() and tried also manually looping with excelReader.Read() but I was still getting empty results. As soon as I updated dll to version 2.1 I got rid of the issue.